# Spring Boot War deployment failed on Docker Tomcat Image - error 404

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, tomcat

i have a problem with the deploying of Spring Boot rest service in a docker container inside a war file. The .war file is correctly unpacked inside the webapps directory and result up and running in "Manager App" menu, but tomcat return 404 when i send the request.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM tomcat:8-jdk17-temurin-focal

EXPOSE 8080
```

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  tomcat:
    container_name: tomcat
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./feedback-service/target/feedback-form.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/feedback-form.war
      - ./tomcat-users.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
      - ./context.xml:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    entrypoint: |
      bash -c 'exec catalina.sh run'
```

The same application, build and launched from IntelliJ IDEA works perfectly.

Any ideas?

Comment: One of the major benefits to using Spring Boot over vanilla spring is that it comes bundled with a http server (tomcat by default). It is intended to eliminate the need to manually manage a tomcat server in this way.

Comment: I completely agree, but the customer thinks his own way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, maybe i found a solution.

**First:**

I checked the Java version matched against the environment. Yes, Tomcat images are varied and handy, but in my case i wanted to exclude environments incompatibility, which it was. I then proceeded to create an ad-hoc Docker image:

```
FROM alpine:latest

LABEL maintainer="viralsrls@gmail.com"

RUN apk update && apk upgrade

//CHANGE WITH YOUR EXACT JAVA VERSION

RUN apk add openjdk17-jre curl bash

RUN mkdir /opt/tomcat

WORKDIR /opt/tomcat

//CHANGE WITH THE SAME TOMCAT EMBEDDED VERSION

RUN curl -O  https://downloads.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-10/v10.1.10/bin/apache-tomcat-10.1.10.tar.gz

RUN tar xvfz apache*.tar.gz --strip-components 1 --directory /opt/tomcat

ADD /manager/tomcat-users.xml /opt/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml

ADD /manager/context.xml /opt/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml

ADD /host/context.xml /opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml

ADD /conf/tomcat.service /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service

EXPOSE 8080
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  tomcat:
    container_name: tomcat
    build: .
    image: tomcat-10.1.10:Alpine
    volumes:
    //YOUR WAR FILE
      - ./feedback-service/target/YOUR-LOCAL-FILE.war:/opt/tomcat/webapps/YOUR-LOCAL-FILE.war
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    entrypoint:
      /opt/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run
```

**Second:**

Check the catalina log of any further problems.

Here the environment repository at your disposal and more details:

[Github](https://github.com/ViralAgency/docker-tomcat10-Java17)